# How to use an Artificial Neural Network to predict the winner of a race based on a set of features?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Suppose there are 1000 people who are competing in a race. Also, data is available about the various features for each runner (age, length of legs, resting heart rate, etc.)

The winners of previous races are also known, along with all the features about each participant.

Is it possible to use an Artificial Neural Network to predict the winner of the race using the information of the past?

If so, how would this be set up? Would the first layer of nodes be the features? What would the output layer represent and how many nodes would there be? Please explain what an ANN would look like for this data. Is it a classification problem?

What would a dataset look like since the goal is to pick one of the racers? Would it work to classify each of racers as a "winner" or "looser?" How would one limit the number of winners to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a problem that ANN can tackle, however just because you have accurate data from participants, it doesn't mean that the data itself is a strong enough predictor for who will win a race.

## Inputs

Each input node (1 for each type of feature like age, length of legs,etc) will need to use an activation function that is intuitive to the type of data you are working with. There are pros and cons for each type of activation function. Most people start with either sigmoid or ReLU for general problems.

## Outputs

Each output will represent the label of the sample date (e.g. who won?), so there will need to be an output for each potential case. Which also means, yes this is a classification problem (not a regression problem).

## Issues

In the case you are describing, it is difficult to predict the outcome of the race without a very large number of features. If you had 500 runners, and 10 features for each, that would mean you need 5000 features total. And not only that - you would need enough sample data where all 500 runners were competing against each other in a controlled case. For obvious reasons, it becomes worrisome to frame the problem this way.

## Modify the Problem

It would be a much more realistic goal to try and predict an individual runner's time in a race (which could be a classification or regression problem). This way the number of features are far fewer, and the dependency on consistent competitors greatly decreases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. What do you mean by 5000 features total? Also, why is it necessary for there to be sample data where all 500 runners are competing against each other in a controlled case? The best runner is to be predicted just by his or her stats; doesn't it not matter if its one person or the other?

Comment: Good question: The reason why a race prediction relies on comparison against participants is because they tell a critical part of the story. A runner's speed is relative its competitors. It's a zero sum game, so to speak. As for your question about 5000 features: I'm making the assumption that there will be an average of 10 "features" collect per runner (10 x 500 runners).

Comment: Do you have an example or know how I can look for something like this? I have a 5v5 team fight and want to try to predict the winner. There are 100 characters. I build my teams so those rarely change, so I have 20 teams.  But my opponents are randomized by the algorithm. Of course, there are 9 billion team combinations. But if you won against ABCDE you probably will win against ABCDZ. Right now I'm using statistics like the baseball to get a prediction of result. But was wondering if can do a ANN to help me with this problem.

Comment: Please open up a new question @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: The thing is not sure how to ask about this because not my area of expertise and if make it too vague probably will be closed. As I said, I'm looking for an example to see if what I want is possible, and so far haven't been any luck.

Comment: The scope for that question is too broad for StackOverflow. Sorry mate. Gotta break it down more. Post code and keep the question specific.